# Force logout facebook oauth

Tags: facebook, logout

I'm using https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id and when the user logs in and accepts the app it goes on to the next page and then finally logs him out using his access token.

My problem is when the user signs in and denies the app. How do you log him out if the access token was never returned?

I've tried the javascript but no luck with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force user to logout when they didn't allow you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will redirect any user denying the app back to your login url with an error specified:

> If the user presses Don't Allow, your app is not authorized. The OAuth
>   Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you
>   passed in the redirect_uri parameter with the following error
>   information:
>
> http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&
>   error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication